# Avoiding adding function-generated None values to comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dict (but can also be list) comprehension of the form

```
my_dict = {bar: foo(bar) for bar in some_range if foo(bar) is not None}
```

This avoids inserting `None` values to the dictionary,  but it also forces me to call `foo` twice over the same element. Is there a way to avoid this and call `foo` only once, without generating a hash with `None` values and later pruning it?

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in ((bar, foo(bar)) for bar in some_range) if v is not None}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `:=` [named expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) for comprehension starting Python 3.8+, it'll avoid calling `foo(bar)` twice:

```py
my_dict = {bar: val for bar in some_range if val:=foo(bar) is not None}
```

**Sample Run:**

```py
>>> result = {i:j for i in range(10) 
        if (j:=(lambda x: x if x%2==0 else None)(i)) is not None}

#output: 
{0: 0, 2: 2, 4: 4, 6: 6, 8: 8}
```

Comment: The syntax is little off - should be ```{bar: val for bar in range(-2, 3, 1) if (val:=foo(bar) is not None) }```   Otherwise, it will get SyntaxError in the current form...

Comment: @DanielHao yeah, it's copied from the question itself

Comment: @DanielHao see the sample run section, I've included the example as well